# docx4j word/googledocs compatibility

Tags: docx4j

I'm creating a program which extracts a docx file, displays it in a Javafx graphic interface with buttons in place of flags put in the docx, and when one puts on it, it modifies the docx taken in input. 
I'm using the docx4j API for extracting and modifying the document.
The problem is that the program fails if i take in entry a docx generated from Microsoft Word. I'm forced to use an artifice.

I'm taking my docx made on Word, then i load it in Google Docs and I use the "Download in .docx format" option. If i directly put the docx from Word in my program, it fails.

I noticed my Word file was two times lighter after being passed trough google doc. Same, if I tale a docx file downloaded from Google Docs, if i open it in Word and modify one letter and save it, he becomes two times heavier. For the record i use word 2008.

That's it, so I'd like to know if someone know what explains this difference.

Thanks

Comment: This is too vague. You need to figure out what the issue is and try some things before asking for help. As a first step, I'd look to compare the XML for your differing instances of a document (i.e. what happens to the underlying `document.xml` file in the docx bundle when you save in Word vs. the version you have from Google Docs).

Comment: Further to what Ben says, are you saying that things work with a Google Docs docx file, but not with a Word docx file?  How exactly does it fail?  Do you have a stack trace?  Can you put the offending docx online somewhere?